# Eclipse will not start after uninstalling Java and reinstalling to a new location

Tags: eclipse, java

I reinstalled the JDK tonight because of the embedded space in Program File... and now Eclipse blows up immediately when starting.  Is there a config file that needs updating?  I tried eclipse -clean with nu luck.

Comment: How many versions of Java do you have installed? Which JDK? Which version of Eclipse?

Comment: are you by any chance using either a 64 bit version of the JDK or of eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while eclipse starting it requires java.exe and javaw.exe. so when you installed it at other places. you should specify its location in PATH variable so that it can be used to locate your JVM.

EDIT: and of course remove the old entry.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I have tried about everything mentioned and then some.  I can issue java and javac from a command prompt just fine.  However, eclipse just flashes the splash screen and vanishes.  I have tried specifying the -vm flag on the cmd line and only get different errors.  Any clues?

Comment: did you try setting JAVA_HOME in environment variables

Answer (score 5):

What OS are you using? You need to let eclipse know where your jdk lives. On windows at least it is in the exclipse.ini, change it to put to your knew jdk and it will work

for example on windows you will need something like this in your eclipse.ini

```
-vm
C:\jdk1.6.0_02\jre\bin\java
```

You can find your eclipse.ini in the root directory of your eclipse installation (ie: where eclipse.exe is)

Answer (score 5):

I know this question has already been solved but i want to share a small detail. if you are using -vm option in eclipse.ini, make sure that it is written before -vmargs option.

in my case below configuration didn't worked

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-vm
C:\ibm_jdk_6\bin\javaw.exe
```

but below configuration worked

```
-vm
C:\ibm_jdk_6\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
```

Answer (score 2):

did you eclipse.ini file in the eclipse directory point to a specific -vm? You may need to change it in your eclipse directory.

Answer (score 2):

You must have fixed this problem by now but I don't see anything in this thread to indicate that.

I just had the same problem. I updated JDK. The next time I tried to start Eclipse it wouldn't. I fixed the problem by removing all older versions of java and setting the new version in my PATH system environment variable. Actually, I also reinstalled my eclipse but I don't think that had anything to do with the solution. By the way, I'm using Eclipse Galileo (Build id: 20090621-0832) and jdk1.6.0_021.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if you have a 64-bit jre and 32-bit eclipse, so just make sure your jre and eclipse build match up!

Answer (score 1):

Use the eclipse clean command; it will make clean and elipse will start

```
   GOTO_Eclipse_Directory > eclipse -clean
```

Refer below url : http://www.coderanch.com/t/454501/vc/eclipse-exe-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Pre append the string in system variable PATH: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin;"
Then every thing will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me Eclipse was not starting because I had two versions of Java 5 & Java 6 installed. I uninstalled 6, and then it started working. So better to see if uninstallation of one version solves the problem.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. On a daily basis I'm developing Java 1.4 project in a new Eclipse environment (requires Java 6 or higher) and I'm not facing any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem When i Installed the java update 38.... 
resolved by uninstalling the update.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse was able to locate the JRE however it failed to launch because the eclipse that I had downloaded was 32 bit and my jdk version was 64bit. I uninstalled 64bit jdk and installed 32bit. Eclipse launched successfully

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to uninstall anything. Just go to the eclipse folder in the eclipse configuration setting and change the class path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin`.